# Codeigniter 3 application bug: adding atributes to Ion-Auth form elements fails

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I am working on an application that requires authentication, in Codeigniter 3. Rather then making my own authentication, I decided to use the **[Ion-Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)** library.

Because I also use Bootstrap 4, I tried to add form-related classes to the form controls. I tried to replace:

```
<p>
  <label for="new_password"><?php echo sprintf(lang('change_password_new_password_label'), $min_password_length);?></label> <br />
    <?php echo form_input($new_password);?>
</p>
```

with:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $attributes = array(
      'class'       => 'form-control',
      'placeholder' => 'New password',
      'value'       => $new_password
    ); ?>
    <label for="new_password"><?php echo sprintf(lang('change_password_new_password_label'), $min_password_length);?></label> <br />
    <?php echo form_input($attributes);?>
  </div>
```

The code above throws the error message `Array to string conversion`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what function you're calling but after looking `Ion-Auth library`, I'm guessing it's `reset_password()`. Regardless,
In your `controller`, the data is passed as -

```
$this->data['new_password'] = [
                                'name' => 'new',
                                'id' => 'new',
                                'type' => 'password',
                                'pattern' => '^.{' . $this->data['min_password_length'] . '}.*$',
                              ];
```

Now `$new_password` is an array in `view`. So, in order to give it value and pass extra attributes, you'll have to write -

```
<?php 
    $new_password['class'] = 'form-control';
    $new_password['placeholder'] = 'New password'; 
    $new_password['value'] = $_POST['new'] ?? ''; // if post request then submitted value else empty

    echo form_input($new_password);
?>
```

This will produce -

```
<input type="password" name="new" value="123456" id="new" pattern="^.{4}.*$" class="form-control" placeholder="New password">
```

### Edit

For `form_submit`, you can write -

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'submit', 'class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success"');
```

or as an array -

```
echo form_submit(array(
                         'name'=>'submit',
                         'value' => 'submit', 
                         'class' => 'btn btn-block btn-md btn-success'
                      )
                 );
```

This will produce -

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
```

See if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $attributes = [
      'class'       => 'form-control',
      'placeholder' => 'New password',
      'value'       => $new_password
    ]; ?>
    <label for="new_password"><?php echo sprintf(lang('change_password_new_password_label'), $min_password_length);?></label> <br />
    <?php echo form_input($attributes);?>
  </div>
```

try this

Comment: I tryed it. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working login form, for whoever needs an example:

```
<?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php $identity['class'] = 'form-control';
            echo lang('login_identity_label', 'identity');
            echo form_input($identity);?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php $password['class'] = 'form-control';
            echo lang('login_password_label', 'password');
            echo form_input($password);?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php $remember['class'] = 'form-control';
            echo lang('login_remember_label', 'remember');
            echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember" class="ml-2"');?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('login_submit_btn'), 'class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-primary"');?>        
    </div>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```